# Как удалить часы, минуты и секунды в дате?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

есть датафрейм в котором столбец типа object отображает даты в таком виде: 2016-06-23T00:00:00
Мне надо оставить в нём только 2016-06-23. Какой метод я могу применить ко всему столбцу?

Answer (score 5):

Разобрался. Для этого надо воспользоваться методом

```
data['column'] = pd.to_datetime(data['column'], format='%Y-%m-%dT')
```

Comment: Куда мы идем? Подумайте о вкладе подобного кода в глобальное потепление.

Comment: @avp, я только что проверил - это очень "зеленый" код!!!  :-D Но его можно сделать еще чуточку зеленее: `data['column'] = pd.to_datetime(data['column'])` - `pd.to_datetime` справится без подсказки формата

Comment: @MaxU, представляете насколько больше потребуется выполнить машинных инструкций для подобного кода, по сравнению с простым кодом на ассемблере (или Си), который заменяет в этих строчках `T` на `'\0'`?

Comment: @avp парни, у меня MSI, так что я итак сделал большой вклад в глобальное потепление когда купил его, но не все сразу стали прожжёнными программистами, которые знают как функционально писать код:)

Comment: @АртёмКрашенинников, наверное даже в Питоне проще всего из такой строки `2016-06-23T00:00:00` тупо взять для ее нового значения первых 9 символов. И вся эта суета с датами не нужна.